# Classic ASP and session Timeouts - keeping track of the session timer?

Tags: session, time, asp-classic

I've been stuck on this problem all week and I'm more than annoyed at the fact that I have to fix this application to meet the security policies the company I work for has... anyways...

I am trying to keep track of a session in a Classic ASP web app. I am able to set the session.timeout as well as a session variable in the session_onstart sub of my gobal.asa file. It works just fine:

```
Sub Session_OnStart
Session("LoggedOn") = true
Session.Timeout = 5
End Sub
```

Next, on one page (to test out a solution to this problem), I have implemented akiller's solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770868/classic-asp-end-of-session-redirect).

I needed to modify the code to look like this:

```
session.asp
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
If Session("LoggedOn") = true Then
Response.Write "{""loggedOn"": true}"
Else 
Response.Write "{""loggedOn"": false}"
End If
%>
```

and:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var checkLoggedOn = function () {

        $.getJSON('session.asp', function (data) {
            if (data.loggedOn = false){
                alert(data.loggedOn);
                //Need to get alert working when session time expires before redirect can be used.
                //window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
            }
        });
    };

    // Call checkLoggedOn every x milliseconds
    setInterval(checkLoggedOn, 30000);
});
</script>
```

Now, what I need to do is find out how to check how much time is left before the session expires. While I can use Javascript code to run a checker like the one above client-side, the time left in the session MUST be checked from the server (to prevent hacking of sessions client-side).

So here's the final steps of what I'm trying to accomplish.

1. Trigger a Session.Abandon when session expires (server-side)
2. Set Session("LoggedOn") to false in the Session_OnEnd event in global.asa
3. session.asp will return false as a result
4. redirect the user where they need to go.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Did you read the update in that answer it kind of gives you a solution using another session value to store `DateAdd("n", Session.Timeout, Now())` giving you exactly when your session should expire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: see [this comment by Lankymart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945243/classic-asp-and-session-timeouts-keeping-track-of-the-session-timer#comment33250887_21945243).

More detailed answer: you can't do what you want.

1. Each time when you a request page when current session is alive, ASP will automatically prolong session lifetime on `timeout` value assigned in this page. In this case, session will live until IIS is restarted.
2. Setting any values to Session collection in `Session_OnEnd` is meaningless: after this event completes, ASP will destroy all Session collection object and remove SessionID from ASP process.
3. Remember, that calling `Session.Abandon` doesn't call event `Session_OnEnd` immediately: see MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I have tried his code in his update. it doesn't work. I had to modify his original code just so it would work properly. I did take some of his ideas with using the date and modified so that it's just time. my problem now is that this code in my session.asp file:`If (Cint(DateDiff("s",Session("LoginExpiration"),Time()))) > 0 Then
        response.write "{""loggedOn"": true}"
    Else
        response.write "{""loggedOn"": false}"
    End If` always returns false when after 1 minute, it should return true... i can't figure out why it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it was decided that it wasn't worth upgrading this project and we're going to keep it on a domain that can only be accessed internally so security fixes are not required.